# External accordion close button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm trying to add a close button inside an accordion, but my jQuery skills are slim to none.

Here's my markup so far:

```
<dl id="accordion">
<dt><a class="openbutton" href="">Click for content</a></dt>
<dd>Content
    <div id="close"><a href="#">Close</a></div>
</dd>
</dl>
```

And:

```
$(function () {
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
});
```

I've attached a fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/FKZtn/1/

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Also if there's a way to when the accordion expands, the viewport scrolls down to the bottom of the accordion content that'd be really helpful too.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FKZtn/3/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
$('#close').click(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({active: false}).click();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FKZtn/3/)**

The accordion has no close method per se, but you can tie the click event of your button to the active option to get the same effect.